# Is there an operator that corresponds to multiplication like integration corresponds to addition?

Tags: integration, analysis

The definite (Riemann) integral of a function $f:D\subseteq\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ from $a$ to $b$ is, by definition, the following limit :
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x$$
for a subdivision of the interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length $\Delta x$, with $x_i$ being an arbitrary value in the $i$-th subinterval. In a sense, an integral is like a "sum" of infinitely (and continuously) many line segments, although this is ambiguous since the value of the integral doesn't change if we modify a countable set of line segments, for example.

I was wondering if there was an operator defined like this :
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x$$
possibly for a specific class of functions $f$ ?

Comment: $\sum(\log\circ f)(x_i)\Delta x=\log(\prod f(x_i)^{\Delta x})$

Comment: There isn't afik, but you can use exp and log to get from multiplicative structures to additive structures and back again. Just like you can define infinite products via series and log.

Comment: Well, taking logs would get us back to $\int \log f(x) \,dx$, so I suppose you want $\exp\left(\int \log f(x)\, dx\right)$.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140507/is-there-a-geometric-interpretation-of-the-product-integral, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral